# How would I find a minimum weight spanning tree for W?

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, trees

If I were to let $W$ be the weighted graph formed by taking a complete graph $K_5$ on five vertices 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 with the weight of each edge $\{x,y\}$ given by $(\{x,y\}) = x + y$, how would I find a minimum weight spanning tree for $W$?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm) or [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim's_algorithm). Both are greedy, and since $K_5$ is not particularly large, you can use whichever.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195872/kruskal-vs-prim) for which situation calls for which algorithm.

There's not much left but to execute them, unless you have a particular concern with the steps of them?